# RSS лента на Kohana 3.2

Tags: php, kohana

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с маленькой не приятностью, пробую сделать RSS ленту на фреймворке Kohana 3.2 с помощью стандартного хелпера Feed. Код я написал, но смотрел, проверял, но видимо то ли я что то не так понял, либо что то не доглядел, прошу подсказать где у меня в коде ошибка. Заранее благодарен.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Content_Rss extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $info = array(
                        'title' => 'Новости сайта agrotimes.net',
                        'language' => 'ru',
                        'description' => 'Новости от Mysite',
                        'link' => '/rss',
                        'pubDate' => time()
                        );

        $news = Model::factory('Content_Rss')->get_newsForRss();

        $items = array();

        foreach($news as $key => &$value) {

            $value['cat_alias'] = Model::factory('Content_Rss')->get_newsCategories($value['news_id']);

            $url = URL::site($value['cat_alias']).'/'.$value['news_alias'];

            $items[] = array(
                        'title' => $value['news_name'],
                        'description' => $value['news_text'],
                        'link' => $url,
                        'pubDate' => date('r', time())
                        );           
        }

        header('Content-Type: text/xml');
        echo feed::create($info, $items);

    }
}
```

Comment: Какая ошибка?  
*Оффтопик, но вы интересно пользуетесь моделями..*

Comment: @Viktor Sychenko,  В следующий раз, чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку **{}** редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была при передаче заголовков, на самом деле :

```
Request::headers('Content-type','text/xml');
```